# Flume configuration

Tags: hadoop, configuration, flume

I am trying to configure Flume. When I run the following command:

```
sudo mv Downloads/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/lib/apache-1.7.0-bin/lib/
```

I get the following error:

> mv: cannot move `Downloads/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' to`/usr/lib/apache-1.7.0-bin/lib/': No such file or directory.

Any one can help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the directory where you browser saves the files? The file should be there.. Unless you have not downloaded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 5 you are asked to download the file:

> Use below link and download flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOTS.jar
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Cl0IfLnRozUHcyNDBJWnNxdHc/view?usp=sharing

Then at the start of step 6 it says:

> Move the flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file from Downloads directory
> to lib directory of apache flume:
>
> Command: `sudo mv Downloads/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/`

This step has assumed that your downloads folder is called `Downloads` and is a subfolder of the one that your console is open at the time. If this is not the case, use the `cd` command to move to the folder where the newly downloaded file exists, and run `sudo mv flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/`

Alternatively if you have access to a desktop on the machine, just cut and paste the downloaded file from where it went when you downloaded it from the internet into the folder `/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/`

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: On step 20, i run the following command and i have error:[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo cp /home/centos/Downloads/flume.conf /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/conf/
cp: cannot stat `/home/centos/Downloads/flume.conf': No such file or directory. I do not have a folder called centos, should i do it manualy or is there any other way to solve it please? Thanks

Comment: I changed "centos" to cloudera as the path indicated and it works. But on the step 23 the command does not work:                                           [cloudera@quickstart Downloads]$ ./bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
bash: ./bin/flume-ng: No such file or directory
How can i solve this problem please?

Comment: Again the folder ./bin/flume-ng does not exist, you will need to find out where it is on your local system and change the command to suit.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter, i fixed it.  But how do i get to this step (24)? https://www.eduonix.com/blog/bigdata-and-hadoop/flume-installation-and-streaming-twitter-data-using-flume/

Comment: Sorry, I do not know anything about Flume at all, I have just been helping you with Linux command line issues. If my answer helped you solve your original issue, please consider marking it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello  Peter, i am trying this command: bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter-flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -n TwitterAgent
bash: bin/flume-ng: No such file or directory
How can i find the right directory?  i have the same problem with the following command: ./bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
bash: ./bin/flume-ng: No such file or directory
I cant find a file with the name ./bin/flume-ng i only found flume-ng    This is the path for the flume-ng : /apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/bin/
can you help me please?

Comment: I used the second command:and i got the following result, can you please see what is wrong? 17/01/31 12:04:08 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source Twitter, type com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
17/01/31 12:04:08 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load source type: com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource, class: com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
........